# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.PersonWorkplaces'. After changing from one-to-many into many-to-many relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've changed from a one-to-many relationship between my two models `Workplace` and `Person`. Entity Framework has correctly created the table that connects them and it's named `WorkplacePersons` and it is also accurately populated. When I try to display a list of people on a workplace I got the exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.PersonWorkplaces'

So for some reason it's looking for `PersonWorkplaces` which doesn't exist, instead of looking for `WorkplacePersons`

Comment: Have you added any mappings in `OnModelCreating`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define `OnModelCreating` in your `DbContext`:

You need to tell Entity Framework which way around you want the mapping, as currently its guessing and getting the tables the wrong way around. in your `OnModelCreating` add something like:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Workplace>()
        .HasMany(x => x.Persons)
        .WithMany(x => x.Workplaces)
        .Map(c =>
        {
            c.MapLeftKey("WorkplaceId");
            c.MapRightKey("PersonId");
            c.ToTable("WorkplacePersons"); 
        });
}
```

Comment: How are you getting the list of people to display?

Comment: @Benji: you said your join table is called WorkplacePersons. This mapping will configure the join table to be this table. What scenario are you in and what do you want your join table to be called exactly?